# Error with Facebook request Dialog using the Javascript SDK, Not working the first time clicked

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have a Facebook app which has a button that brings up the Facebook requests dialog. When this button is clicked the first time the page loads, the request dialog pops up in the a new window, and this new window doesn't work half the time (freezes up and requires me to close all browser windows). but on the times where i does work and lets me close it, and i click my button again, it opens correcty, in a dialog with the shadow and everything.

My question is, how can arrange it to not open in a new window the first time click and possible close my app. Here is my code that runs the dialog:

```
//shows pop up window for inviting friends
function Invite()
{
    FB.init(
    {       
        appId:'<?echo $app_id;?>', cookie:true,
        status:true, xfbml:true 
    });
    FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'apprequests', 
        message: 'Insert Message Here'
    });
}
```

and here is my button code if that matters:

```
`<button onclick="Invite();">Invite Friends!</button>`
```

i am using he Javascript SDK. I have searched for this, but go nothing.

In my console, when the dialog opens in a new window, it shows the error:
    Image corrupt or truncated:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call FB.init() function outside from Invite() function. FB need some time to load itself. Try to place FB.init() separate in top of your  page (after body tag).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I changed my code and it seems to work now. What i did was on document.ready, i loaded FB.init().